# Magento case sensitivity issue on Windows server

Tags: magento, iis-7, url-routing

I am attempting to configure a Magento website on a Windows server (IIS 7) server. In most cases the website seems to work fine, but in seemly random instances, the capitalization of "index.php" in the URL changes to "Index.php" (or vice-versa), and causes a 404 error.

I.e. sometimes when I open any particular page, I see a URL in the form of `http://mywebsite/index.php/payment`, but sometimes I'll get `http://mywebsite/Index.php/payment`, showing me the 404 not found error. Then, If I manually change from Index.php to index.php in the address field, the page loads correctly.

The frustrating part is that sometimes the capital "Index.php" works and the lowercase "index.php" causes the error, but other times it's the other way around, with no rhyme nor reason I can determine.
**EDIT:** It seems to change every time I refresh the indexes... Still not sure why though.

Has anyone encountered this before, or suggest anything that might help fix the situation?

Answer (score 0):

Just be super carefull  of your naming conventions.
Linux is case-insensitive.
Windows is case-sensitive.

First thing : why do you try to access to your site with an uppercase Index.php ? (standard magento file is index.php in lowercase)

Next, do you know you can hide the "index.php" string part in the URL via Backoffice configuration ?

Finally, (I don't know if it happen to you but it's good to remember) put the minimum uppercase letters possible in your PHP classes. It will simplify your life when it comes to call it :

Example : a File `./Model/Folder/Phpclass.php` will be called `Mage::getModel('module/folder_phpclass')`

but a file `./Model/Folder/PhpClass.php` will be called `Mage::getModel('module/folder_phpClass')`

First option is error-free, second one can be tricky ...

Comment: As stated in the question, it randomly switches from the lower to uppercase, if I could make it always default to lowercase and have that work, I would. My issue is, it's not doing that

Comment: Sorry but in your question you're talking about switch from uppercase to lowercase, meaning you're considering the uppercase the normal case which is not... btw good luck

Comment: I don't really consider the upper case the normal case. I guess I see how you might see that I do. I'll edit the question slightly